# c# sql update - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am working on a project that needs a database.
I have found a tutorial which I've seen in Youtube, and it demonstrates how to connect and edit data with SQL Server 2005.
But when I tried it, I receive this error `InvalidOperationException`

This is the whole edit code

```
con.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//load all records from sample table
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from sampleEdit where ID=" +
    textBox1.Text + " ", con);
da.Fill(dt);

//start the editing of the selected record
dt.Rows[0].BeginEdit();

dt.Rows[0][1] = textBox2.Text;

//stop the editing
dt.Rows[0].EndEdit();

//declare the sql commandbuilder that allow saving of records
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

//update the database
da.Update(dt);

//close the connection
con.Close();

//call the method that display the record to the gridview
displayRecords();
```

The error shows at the update part.
What should be the problem?

this was the full exception error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.  
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatingRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatingEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, DataRow dataRow)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
at DatabaseConnect3.Form1.btnEdit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: It helps to include the full text of the exception thrown. Also it wouldn't hurt to link the Youtube video if it is publicly viewable.

Comment: @Guvante, sorry i forgot the link. just downloaded the video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source table is invalid because you most likely didn't define a primary key on the table. Just make the ID column the primary key of the table and the code should work.